# I18n for attribute errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, internationalization, rails-i18n

Does exist a way to do something like this:

```
Model.human_attribute_name :attr
```

but with errors?

Something like this...

```
Model.human_error_name :attr, :error
```

For example:

```
Ticket.human_error_name :ticket_type_id, :no_tickets_left
```

I want to avoid this on my views:

```
I18n.t("activerecord.errors.models.ticket.attributes.ticket_type_id.no_tickets_left")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I know of, but it is very easy to add such a method to all your models:

```
module Hemju
  module HumanErrorName
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def human_error_name(attr, error)
      I18n.t("activerecord.errors.models.#{self.class.to_s}.attributes.#{attr}.#{error}")
    end
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, Hemju::HumanErrorName)
```

Activating the extension in initializer:

```
require 'hemju/human_error_name'
```

Now every model has a 'human_error_name' method. Remember, every time you change the method, you have to restart the server.